# Virtual Machine deployment "VMimage ReourceNotFound Exception" using Azure-SDK-for-Java

Tags: java, azure, sdk

I wanted to deploy a VM using an image in my blob store. I followed the example here:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/management-compute/src/test/java/com/microsoft/windowsazure/management/compute/VirtualMachineOperationsTests.java

but since I am using my VM image, so i defined the VMimageName and Medialocation in the "Role" definition

```
  val imagename = "xxxxxxxxxx"
  val uri = "http://xxxxstore.blob.core.windows.net/vhds"
  role.setVMImageName(imagename)
  role.setMediaLocation(new java.net.URI(uri))
```

and I make sure that i didn't set the OSVirtualHardDisk or ConfigurationSet

```
   //role.setOSVirtualHardDisk(oSVirtualHardDisk)
   //role.setConfigurationSets(configurationSetArray)
```

Even I can see my images by using the "list" call

```
    computeManagementClient.getVirtualMachineOSImagesOperations.listAsync()
```

But when I initiated the deployment

```
    computeManagementClient.getVirtualMachinesOperations.beginCreatingDeploymentAsync(AzureParametersJavaSDK.hostedServiceName, AzureParametersJavaSDK.parameters)
```

I got the following exception

**VM deployment failed : com.microsoft.windowsazure.exception.ServiceException: ResourceNotFound: VMImage xxxxxxxxxx not found.**

Does anyone encounter/report the similar problem before?